# Wordpress pagination not working in static front page

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-wordpress-pages

can anyone please help me with my pagination.As in wordpress when I assign a static page as front page it is not working.Please check the [link](http://demo5.ntsplhosting.com/blog).

Comment: can you please show me the php code of static page. ?

Comment: Thanks for your help.but it is not working.

Comment: @Govind Kumar,Which page are you talking about?I am not getting.Please clear.

Comment: Please try  my answer ,

Comment: where is the answer?

Comment: click on this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/40779911/4655242

Answer (score 0):

Add this code inside your Theme's `functions.php` file.

> The **pre_get_posts** action gives developers access to the $query
>   object by reference (any changes you make to $query are made directly
>   to the original object - no return value is necessary).

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($query) {

    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_front_page()) {

        // get the page query string value.
        $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

        // set current page query string.
        $query->set('paged', $paged);

        // set posts_per_page 
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 9); // remove if already assigned.
    }

});
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

I do this:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {

    $paged = get_query_var('paged');

} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {

    $paged = get_query_var('page');

} else {

    $paged = 1;

}
```